# jQuery reference after AJAX call

Tags: jquery, ajax

After an AJAX call i'm getting an HTML:

```
This is a new Title <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="goBackLink"><img src="../images/go-back.png" /></a>
```

i wrote this code:

```
$('#goBackLink').click(function() {
            $('.msgBoxConverstion').slideUp('slow', function (){
                $('.msgBoxContent').slideDown('slow'); 
            });
        });
```

but from some reason it doesn't work.
before you say anything, yes i double checked the classes name and they are exists.

this is the full code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#messagesLink').click(function() {
            $('#wrapper').fadeTo('slow', 0.5, function (){
                $('#messageBox').fadeIn();
            });
        });

        $('#exitLink').click(function() {
            $('#messageBox').fadeOut(function (){
                $('#wrapper').fadeTo('slow', 1); 
            });
        });

        $('#goBackLink').click(function() {
            $('.msgBoxConverstion').slideUp('slow', function (){
                $('.msgBoxContent').slideDown('slow'); 
            });
        });

        $('.msgBoxContent p').click(function (){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '../core/ajax_handler.php',
                data: ({
                    ajaxHook: 'getMessageReplies',
                    messageID: $(this).attr('class')
                }),
                success: function ( messageLayout ){
                    var message = $.parseJSON( messageLayout );
                    $('.msgBoxContent').slideUp('slow', function() {
                        $('.msgBoxConverstion').html( message.replies ).slideDown('slow');
                    });
                    $('.msgBoxHeader').html( message.title );
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
<div id="messageBox">
    <div class="msgBoxHeader">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="exitLink"><img src="../images/cross.png" /></a>
        [#-LANG::X_MSGS_FROM_X-#]
    </div>
    <div class="msgBoxContent">
        [#-DATA::GET_USER_MESSAGES-#]
    </div>
    <div class="msgBoxConverstion">

    </div>
    <div class="msgBoxBottom"></div>
</div>
```

Thanks again :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Statically written click handlers using `click` or `bind` will not pick up dynamically added content.  You'll need to use `on` to accomplish this.

```
$(document).on("click", '#goBackLink', function() {
     $('.msgBoxConverstion').slideUp('slow', function (){
          $('.msgBoxContent').slideDown('slow'); 
     });
});
```

Note that this will listen for **all** clicks that occur **anywhere** on your page.  Ideally, if you're guaranteed that this `goBackLink` anchor will always be added inside of some container, say, a div named `foo`, then just listen for clicks on `foo`

```
$('#foo').on("click", '#goBackLink', function() {
     $('.msgBoxConverstion').slideUp('slow', function (){
           $('.msgBoxContent').slideDown('slow'); 
     });
});
```

Comment: thanks mate, i thought about using "on" function but i wasn't sure how.
you rock!

Comment: +1 for right answer and also for pointing out my fault without downvote. :)

Comment: @dku.rajkumar - sure thing :)  Feel free to correct your answer - it's not plagiarizing, it's just making sure new visitors don't see incorrect things when they browser here

Answer (score 1):

You're adding the click event to `#goBackLink` before it exists, so nothing will happen. Use jQuery's `on()` function on the body. Like this:

```
$('body').on('click', '#goBackLink'), function() {
    $('.msgBoxConverstion').slideUp('slow', function (){
        $('.msgBoxContent').slideDown('slow'); 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this you are loading from the response of ajax call which means after the window has been loaded. so you should use `on` event handler.

```
$('body').on('click','#goBackLink',function() {
      $('.msgBoxConverstion').slideUp('slow', function (){
            $('.msgBoxContent').slideDown('slow'); 
       });
});
```

Comment: This won't work because ```#goBackLink``` doesn't exist yet. You have to delegate the event to an element higher up the DOM tree.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the live() method for binding the event instead of click.  like below

```
$('#goBackLink').live('click',function() {
    $('.msgBoxConverstion').slideUp('slow', function (){
        $('.msgBoxContent').slideDown('slow');
    });
});
```

By definition live() method will "Attach an event handler for all elements which match the current selector, **now and in the future**."  So this should work when you replace the *#goBackLink* element after successful ajax call.